# In Perl, how can I use regular expressions to skip input lines containing digits?

Tags: regex, perl, input, skip

I've got a list like this:

```
Bicycles: Childrens  
289  
Bicycles: Mountain Bikes  
928  
Bicycles: Road Bikes  
870  
Camping & Outdoors Equipment  
761  
Canoes, Kayaks, Row-Boats  
231  
Climbing Equipment  
120  
Freeweights and Home Gyms  
583  
GPS and Locators  
104  
Golf Equipment  
1,223  
Other Fitness Equipment  
668
```

I just need to skip lines that are numbers or blank

```
if (($line =~ /0..9/) || ($line eq "")){}  
else{
```

Comment: What behavior OP wants for lines with mix content, such as "I am number 1" ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write

```
while (<>) {
  next unless /[^\d,\s]/;
    :
}
```

your program will skip all lines that contain only digits, commas, and whitespace.

This program shows the idea

```perl
use strict;
use warnings

while (<DATA>) {
  next unless /[^\d,\s]/;
  print;
}

__DATA__
Bicycles: Childrens  
289  
Bicycles: Mountain Bikes  
928  
Bicycles: Road Bikes  
870  
Camping & Outdoors Equipment  
761  
Canoes, Kayaks, Row-Boats  
231  
Climbing Equipment  
120  
Freeweights and Home Gyms  
583  
GPS and Locators  
104  
Golf Equipment  
1,223  
Other Fitness Equipment  
668
```

**output**

```
Bicycles: Childrens  
Bicycles: Mountain Bikes  
Bicycles: Road Bikes  
Camping & Outdoors Equipment  
Canoes, Kayaks, Row-Boats  
Climbing Equipment  
Freeweights and Home Gyms  
GPS and Locators  
Golf Equipment  
Other Fitness Equipment
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print $line if $line !~ /[0-9]/ and $line =~ /\S/;
```

[perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). You'll learn more if you put some effort into it.

Comment: :-) if (( $line =~ /[0-9]/ or $line eq "")){}

Comment: Please explain what you mean by that comment using English. I wrote the line in my answer for a specific reason: 1) I do not know if you `chomp`ed input 2) You use the word ***blank*** referring to a line and a line containing nothing but blanks is still a blank line to me, and 3) I do not like empty blocks following `if`s. The line above says "`print` if the line does not contain any digits and it contains some non-space characters. If you need something else, say so.

Comment: I'm sorry. I just modified your answer to work with my code. It's not a crucial script. It worked great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($line !~ /^[\d,]*[\n\r]*$/) {
  # do something
}   
else {
  # blank or "digits & comas" only line
}
```

By "blank" I mean empty string with optional end of line (in case you don't use `chomp`)

Answer (score 0):

next if (!$line || $line != int($line));

First is blank values check, the second one checks whether this value is integer or not.